# javascript: What does for void mean in context of a for loop?

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain this line of JS to me?

```
for (var X = void 0; list_name.length > 1;) { 
        XXXXX
        }
if (X):
        XXXX
```

I noticed that if I invert the two parts of the expression '(var X = void 0)' and 'list_name.length > 1' then the script throws the syntax error ('expected an identifier and saw var').

Is it like 'as long as the list has a length of >1, initialise a variable with the name X and do the loop, if the list is not longer than length 1, move into the if(X) part of the loop?'

Comment: It initializes `X` to `undefined`.

Comment: `void` has the same meaning outside a loop as well.

Comment: thanks. Out of curiosity, can i write this line any other way? Could i write 'for list_name.length > 1' and then define var X on the next line, or is the way in the question the general conventional way this is written.